# How to make my HDDs stay awake?

Tags: hard-drive, sleep

Windows is installed on an SSD but most of the content like videos and even some applications are on my HDDs. 
When I'm not accessing content from HDDs, they go to a sleep mode and when I access them, my computer freezes for a 1-2 seconds before I can open files on or whatnot. 
It kinda defeats the purpose of having fast SSD if HDDs slow me down.
Is there a way to let them stay awake at all time?

Comment: See if this helps: It's a Windows Power Settings panel instructional that allows you to customise what Windows does with various devices and their power states: http://www.fantomdrives.com/helpdesk/faq.php?cid=7&answer=80 - the page shows real Windows panels, it is not a product or add-on.

Answer (score 0):

The option in Power Settings related to drives is  *Turn off Hard Disk After* and it specifies how long after the most recent access before the HDDs power off. Set this to always on and that should do it.

Note that if you change power plans, you will have to make the setting for the new power plan as well.